# How to skip horizontally by the negative amount of \hoffset?

Tags: xetex, plain-tex

I tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
\hskip -\hoffset
\hskip -\the\hoffset
\hskip 0pt minus\hoffset
\hskip 0pt minus\the\hoffset
```

What is the right syntax to reference `hoffset`?

#### Update

Complete example:

```tex
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfpageheight=297mm
\hsize=\pdfpagewidth \advance\hsize by -50mm
\vsize=\pdfpageheight \advance\vsize by -50mm
\advance\hoffset by -1in \advance\hoffset by 25mm
\advance\voffset by -1in
\def\falz{\vrule width25mm height.1mm depth0pt}
\hbox {The distance between the paper border and the left side of the
  line is 25mm, because hoffset is set to 25mm.}
\hbox{\hskip-25mm\falz Skipping by the numerical value works.}
\hbox{\hskip-\hoffset\falz But skipping by -hoffset does not work.}
\bye
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? \hoffset is zero by default, so normally nothing should happen.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer \hoffset is 1in by default. And in my case it is 25mm: `\advance\hoffset by -1in \advance\hoffset by 25mm`. And I want to skip back to the paper border to render a fold mark.

Comment: no try `\showthe\hoffset`, it will give 0pt. Beside this `\hskip-\hoffset ` should work.

Comment: @cevin `\hoffset` is initially 0pt. If you subtract `1 in` and add `25mm`, then `-1.1381pt` remains, which is  a tiny distance that you will hardly notice (1 in = 25.4 mm)

Comment: You're wrong about the default value of `\hoffset`: it is `0pt`. The initial reference point is 1in from the left and top margin. Check the documentation of `pdftex` for `\pdfhorigin` and `\pdfvorigin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard reference point is 1in from the left and the top margins. If you want it to be 25mm from both, you can do

```
\advance\hoffset\dimexpr25mm-1in\relax
\advance\voffset\dimexpr25mm-1in\relax
```

or, since it's known that 1in = 25.4mm,

```
\advance\hoffset -0.4mm
\advance\voffset -0.4mm
```

A simpler way with `pdftex` would be to do

```
\pdfhorigin=25mm
\pdfvorigin=25mm
```

If I compile the following with `xetex`

```
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfpageheight=297mm
\hsize=\pdfpagewidth \advance\hsize by -50mm
\vsize=\pdfpageheight \advance\vsize by -50mm
\advance\hoffset-0.4mm
\advance\voffset-0.4mm

\vglue -24mm % back up vertically by almost 25mm
\vglue-\topskip % remove the topskip
\moveright-24mm\vbox{\hrule width 3cm depth 4pt}

\bye
```

As you see there is 1mm of white space on the left and above the rule.

[image]

If I use 25mm, I get

[image]

Note that XeTeX doesn't really know anything about how the output is placed on the physical page: it is the same as TeX, in this respect, and relies on the output driver. In the case of TeX a conformant DVI driver will use (1in,1in) as origin and the same holds for `xdvipdfmx`.

Comment: When I try to set `\pdfhorigin`, I get the error: `! Undefined control sequence. l.7 \pdfhorigin`

Comment: @ceving \pdfhorigin is for pdftex, but you seem to use xetex.

Comment: with xetex you could try `\special{dvipdfmx:config x 71.13188}
\special{dvipdfmx:config y 71.13188}`  (not quite sure about the number, the docu is a bit unclear here, I used 25mm in pt)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The [XeTeX](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf) reference does not say anything about a origin.

Comment: you need to look in the docu of dvipdfmx and dvipdfm.

Comment: Actually it is possible that the docu is wrong and could `\special{dvipdfmx:config x 25mm}` work.