# Printing text at top of page with 0 separation at the top, using own class file

Tags: margins, documentclass-writing

I want to produce a LaTeX document that looks like the following:

[image: text typed at top]

That is, when you start typing text, it appears at the top left part of the page and continues from there.

In order to achieve that, I am building my own LaTeX document class file (partly as a learning exercise).

What I have at the moment is the following:

```latex
% myclass.cls file\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass} [2022/06/12 v0.1 My Class]
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\pdfpageheight=20cm
\pdfpagewidth=20cm

\pdfhorigin=0mm
\pdfvorigin=0mm
\hoffset=0cm
\voffset=0cm

\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep {0cm}
\setlength\topskip {0cm}
\setlength\topmargin {0cm}
```

to which corresponds the following document:

```latex
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas. Bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed. Lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh.
\end{document}
```

But the output is the following:

[image: current output]

As far as I know, I defined to length `0` all the parameters of the top side of the page, but still there is some gap. What parameter is responsible for that gap?

A minor question, but still important: Why there is no line break?

Comment: Don't you also have to specify the paper size, size of the textblock, etc?

Comment: I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31976) to change the paper size, and I discovered in the geometry manual and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571574/) about `pdf{h,v}origin` and `{h,v}offset`. But still setting them to 0 doesn't yield the desired result.

Comment: Are you talking about the horizontal gap before first letter `L`?

Comment: @Tom Yes, I want the L of Lorem to be just at the beginning of the printing area.

Comment: @tush That's `\parindent`. You should also set `\textwidth` and `\textheight` to have line break and page break.

Comment: @Tom Right you are! How do I set line breaks and page breaks for those two dimensions?

Comment: @tush give some values to `\textwidth` and `\textheight`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137108/discussion-between-tush-and-tom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
  \setlength{\topskip}{5mm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{2mm}

  \begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \end{document}
```

[image]